# Outlook Add-ins : When user close/cancel the task pane from outlook add-in and I must detect any callback/event to log the custom data

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing an Outlook add-in using React with the below references.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial?view=outlook-js-1.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane?view=outlook-js-1.8

**When user close/cancel the task pane from outlook add-in and I must detect any callback/event to log the custom data.**

I tried different approaches below

1. added the onbeforeunload event to the window into my react Usercomponent.

   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => 
   {
     debbugger;
      //// didnt get hit debugger user closes the task pane from the outlook add-in.
   });
2. I have tried with the componentwillunmount

   componentWillUnmount()
     {
       console.log("componentWillUnmount");
      debbugger;
      //// didnt get hit debugger when user closes the task pane.
     }
3. tried with the below code and didn't get any call back event

   Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived,this.Handler);
   Handler(input : any): any {
     console.log(input);
      debbugger;
      //// didnt get hit debugger when user closes the task pane.
     }
4. Add callback for ItemChanged event in Office.initialize()

   Office.initialize = async () => {

   Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, (events: any) =>{
   debugger;
      //// didnt get hit debugger when user closes the task pane.
   console.log(events);
    });

Reference for all available events for Office api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=word-js-preview

Any suggestions about how I could achieve this?

I just need a callback event or method to log my custom data when the user closes the task pane

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently OfficeJS does not support TaskPaneClose event. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.